# Unity Google VR SDK Main Camera showing Game Objects Behind Left and Right Cameras

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm trying to get a basic VR app up and running on iOS with the Unity Google VR SDK and I've run into a strange issue where my game objects are appearing behind the left and right camera views in cardboard view. In the HeadsetDemo app that is provided along with the SDK, there's just a black background but in my app that background is the default grey-blue skybox color and renders any game objects that I have in my scene. Does anyone know how to hide game objects from that main camera?